# Managing and Closing Dynamically created SQL connections in .net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a c# windows form application that connects to databases dynamically where each user may connect to different databases.

The current implementation is as follows:

Connection Repository that contains a dynamically populated list of connections (per user).

When a user initiates a request that requires a database connection the respective connection is looked up from the connection repository ,opened , and then used in the user request .

**Code Sample from the connection repository**

```
public class RepoItem
{
    public string databasename;
    public SqlConnection sqlcnn;
}

public class ConnectionRepository
{
    private List<RepoItem> connectionrepositroylist;

    public SqlConnection getConnection(String dbname)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = (from n in connectionrepositroylist
                             where n.databasename == dbname
                             select n.sqlcnn).Single;

        cnn.Open();
        return cnn;
    }
}
```

*sorry for any code errors i just improvised a small version of the implementation for demonstration purpose.*

I'am not closing connections after a command execution because it may be used by another command simultaneously.

**The questions are:**

- Should i be worried about closing the connections ?
- Does connection close automatically if it is idle for a specific period ?

I have a method in mind to implement a timer in the created Connection Repository and check for idle connections through the `Executing` `ConnectionState Enumeration` and close them manually.
Any suggestions are welcome .

When i want a specific connection i call the getConnection function in the ConnectionRepository class and pass the database name as a parameter.

PS: I didn't post the complete implemented code because it is quite big and includes the preferences that affect the populating of the connection list.

Comment: `SqlConnection` already does pooling by itself - no need to implement such a thing. See [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling].

Comment: If this is a winforms app then it must be running on multiple machines.  How many machines will it be running on?  Pooling works on each machine, but does not work across machines.  So if you have 100 different people running this app, you will have 100 open connections.  Pooling works when you open and CLOSE connections, it saves you from having to do the hard resource work of reopening.  But it will never just close your connection if it is idle, it will close it in the pool if no one tries to reopen it for a given period of time.  Best practice is to close it when you are done with it.

Comment: Actually, I don't see a reason for this class at all, when you can simply save the connection strings along with the dbname in app.config.

Comment: @ZoharPeled. I mentioned that the connection definitions are created dynamically. So we cannot use app.config. i wish you read the question thoroughly before commenting ..

Comment: @JM_, yes it is a winforms app as stated in the question's tag.And yes it may be running on multiple machines. And because each user may connect to a different collection of databases i have to manage the creation of connections in my app.

Comment: Ok, so the users creates the connection strings. What else can the users do? I'm guessing the next step would be to create sql statements to run against whatever database they choose, right? If you could add some more context it will be easier to answer the question.

Comment: Well I think the answers to your questions where No, the connection does not close automatically and No, you should not have to monitor those connections periodically.  Rather you should close them immediately after using them and connection pooling will handle the low level opens and closes for you.  Even when one process uses that connection right after another.  That is best practice as far as I know.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, sorry for the short code, the actual code is a bit large. And yes you are right about that connection strings are made per user , and use in statements to run against whatever database they choose. Any missing detail i'll be happy to provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest not to return the `SQLConnection` to the calling method at all.
Instead, create a method that will accept an `Action<SqlConnection>`, create the connection inside a `using` block, and execute the action inside that block

This way you know that the connection will always be correctly closed and disposed, while giving the using code the freedom to do whatever it needs:

```
public class RepoItem
{
    public string databasename;
    public SqlConnection sqlcnn;
}

public class DatabaseConnector
{
    private List<RepoItem> connectionrepositroylist;

    private SqlConnection GetConnection(String dbname)
    {
        return (from n in connectionrepositroylist
                where n.databasename == dbname
                select n.sqlcnn).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public void Execute(String dbname, Action<SqlConnection> action)
    {
        using (var cnn = GetConnection(dbname))
        {
            if (cnn != null) // in case dbname is not in the list...
            {
                cnn.Open();
                action(cnn);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then, to execute an sql statement you can do something like this:

```
public void ExecuteReaderExample(string dbName, string sql)
{
    Execute("dbName",
    connection =>
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // do stuff with data form the database
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, you can also wrap the `SqlCommand` in a method like this.
I've been working with this approach for quite some time now, and as far as I can tell it's working well. In fact, It's working so well I've published [a project on git hub](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper) based on this approach.
It saves you a lot of the plumbing when dealing with ado.net, by wrapping the connection, command, reader and adapter much the same way.
Feel free to download it and adapt to your needs.

P.S.
To answer your questions directly:

> Should i be worried about closing the connections ?

Yes, you should.

> Does connection close automatically if it is idle for a specific period ?

No, it doesn't.

However, implementing a method like I suggested will handle closing and disposing the connection object for you, so you don't need to worry about it.

### Update

As Yahfoufi wrote in his comment, this design has a flaw, since multiple commands are using the same instance of `SqlConnection`, you are risking closing the connection while other commands are running. 
However, fixing this design flaw is very easy - instead of holding `SqlConnection` in `RepoItem` you can simply hold the connection string:

```
public class RepoItem
{
    public string DatabaseName {get; set;}
    public string ConnectionString {get; set;}
}
```

Then you change the `GetConnection` method like this:

```
    private SqlConnection GetConnection(String dbname)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(from n in connectionrepositroylist
                where n.databasename == dbname
                select n.sqlcnn).SingleOrDefault());
    }
```

Now each `Execute` method is working on it's own individual instance of `SqlConnection` so you don't need to worry about closing in the middle of some other command executing.

**However**, While we are on the subject of refactoring, I would suggest removing the `RepoItem` class all together and instead of using a `List<RepoItem>` to hold the connection strings simply use a `Dictionary<string, string>`, where the database name is the key and the connection string is the value. This way you can only have one connection string per database name, and your `GetConnection` method is simplified to this:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> connectionrepositroylist;

    private string GetConnectionString(String dbname)
    {
        return connectionrepositroylist.ContainsKey(dbname) ? connectionrepositroylist[dbname] : "";
    }
```

So, the complete DatabaseConnector class will look like this:

```
public class DatabaseConnector
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> connectionrepositroylist;

    private string GetConnectionString(String dbname)
    {
        return connectionrepositroylist.ContainsKey(dbname) ? connectionrepositroylist[dbname] : "";
    }

    public void Execute(String dbname, Action<SqlConnection> action)
    {
        var connectionString = GetConnectionString(dbname);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {    
            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                action(cnn);
            }
        }
    }

    // Of course, You will need a way to populate your dictionary - 
    // I suggest having a couple of methods like this to add, update and remove items.
    public bool AddOrUpdateDataBaseName(string dbname, string connectionString)
    {
        if(connectionrepositroylist.ContainsKey(dbname))
        {
            connectionrepositroylist[dbname] = connectionString;
        }
        else
        {
            connectionrepositroylist.Add(dbname, connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer , but closing the connection will affect other commands that use the same connection and are under execution ?

Comment: @Yahfoufi Good catch. However it's a flaw of the OP's original design that can be fixed simply by storing the connection string Instead of `SqlConnection` in `RepoItem`. Will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: So, what I said then ;o)

Comment: @Pete yes. Though believe it or not, I didn't read that far into your answer until now :-)

Comment: @Yahfoufi seems we have much in common : in my profile it's "Programmer by day,
try to sleep by night."

Comment: Hey @ZoharPeled i have a question ..
after monitoring the application it seems that the connections are not disposed .
the following code calls the GetConnection method
the connection declared with using statement is disposed but the one created inside the getconnection method is not.
the current code is leading to "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

Comment: @Yahfoufi: I've edited my answer - Now you don't have a GetConnection method anymore, instead you have a GetConnectionString method.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that ADO.Net manages your connection pools dynamically, so there's minimal overhead in you dynamically opening and closing connections in code. There's a good document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) if you want to look through the detail.

To answer the specific questions you've raised:

> *Should i be worried about closing the connections ?*

Yes, but not for the reasons you may think. Microsoft encourage you to close your connections, so as to return them to the pool for (re)use elsewhere in your code. Closing the connection doesn't actually *close* it - it merely returns the underlying connection to the pool. Failure to close your connections properly can lead to delays in them being returned to the pool, thus adversely affecting your applications performance as more connections need to be added to the pool to cope with demand.

> Does connection close automatically if it is idle for a specific
>   period ?

A connection is only returned to the pool when it's Dispose or Finalise methods get called. If you create a connection and drop it into a static container then it will not be returned to the pool at all. As such, your ConnectionRepository may actually be harming performance.

> I have a method in mind to implement a timer in the created Connection
>   Repository and check for idle connections

This is unnecessary - close your connections to allow them to return to the pool. This way they will be available for other threads to use

Personally, I'd suggest that you modify your RepoItem class to store connection strings, rather than connection objects, and let ADO.Net's pooling do all the heavy lifting.

```
public static class ConnectionRepository
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Connections = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    public static bool Contains(string key)
    {
        return Connections.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public static void Add(string key, string connectionString)
    {
        Connections.Add(key, connectionString);
    }

    public static SqlConnection Get(string key)
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(Connections[key]);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
}
```

With this in place, you can query the database as follows:

```
public static void foo()
{
    using (var con = ConnectionRepository.Get("MyConnection"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", con))
    {
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //...
    }
}
```

Once the query has executed and the connection is no longer required, the using() block calls its Dispose() method and releases the underlying connection back to the pool for re-use.

Answer (score 1):

As @tinudu says, the [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class reuses existing connections automatically - you don't have to implement that yourself. See [SQL Server Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

If you create the SqlConnection object in a [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement, C# will close the connection automatically as required.

Wrapping the whole thing (create connection, open, run query, close connection) in a function is the best idea. You can put the function in a repository base-class, so it is available to all your repositories.

You would need several functions for the different types of SQL query (select, update, stored proc) but you only need to write one of each - they will get reused.

Answer (score 1):

> if you worried about so many conditions let say parallel execution as
>   well so consider reserving connections for app and close all at once
>   when app is closing.

```
public class RepoItem
{
    public string databasename;
    public SqlConnection sqlcnn;
}

public class ConnectionRepository
{
    private List<RepoItem> connectionrepositroylist;

    public SqlConnection getConnection(String dbname)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = (from n in connectionrepositroylist
                             where n.databasename == dbname
                             select n.sqlcnn).Single;
        if (cnn!= null && cnn.State == cnn.Closed) // Impelement other checks as well
        {
         cnn.Open();
        }
         return cnn;
    }
}
```

> Implement CloseConnections and call while application closing i.e

**Application.ApplicationExit**  event

```
 public void CloseConnections()
    {
        foreach (var connection in connectionrepositroylist)
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) // check other conditions
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //logging or special handling
            }
        }

    }
```

**Points to be note**
If some query is still executing and user tries to shut down or close the 
    app can consider following implementations

1. Wont allow the application shutdown . Callback delegate will help in this 
   case to ensure that query is returned.
2. Force stop and close the connection

Answer (score 1):

It is a better Practice to close the sqlconnection manually, Since it can release the connection which can be used for other processes. Also note that you should open the connection as much as late you can and close it early as possible.